# How to integrate threejs editor or any custom editor in react to edit threejs components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, 3d, threejs-editor

I’ve installed r3f js via npm and I’ve been render a simple 3d object. But i want to control and edit that object, i realized that there is tool call three js editor. So i want to use three js editor in my web app. My question is how to integrate three js Editor in my web app.

PS: i’m new in three js

Excepted: I need to import a glb file into my canvas and update some texture over it, and to add some Logo's and Text over it using mesh material over that model and to handle position, scale & rotation of those updated elements individually based on user selection. I tried updating texture over click. But textures are getting streatched on some places.

Code:

```
function Model({ glbPath, textures }) {
        const shirt = useRef();
        const size = new Vector3(0.15, 0.15, 0.15);
        const decalMaterial = new MeshStandardMaterial({
            transparent: true,
            depthWrite: false,
            polygonOffset: true,
            polygonOffsetFactor: -1,
        });

        const state = useThree();

        const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF(glbPath);

        let currentTexturePath;
        const [currentTextureIndex, setCurrentTextureIndex] = useState(0);
        if (svgOverlay.length > 0) {
            currentTexturePath = svgOverlay[currentTextureIndex]?.svgSrc;
        }

        decalMaterial.map = useTexture(
            currentTexturePath ? currentTexturePath : "./img/three2.png"
        );
        const texture = useTexture(
            currentTexturePath ? currentTexturePath : "./img/three2.png"
        );

        // Create a new material with the loaded texture
        const material = new MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture });

        const AddDecal = (point, face) => {
            const m = new Mesh(
                new DecalGeometry(shirt.current, point, face.normal, size),
                decalMaterial
            );
            setCurrentTextureIndex(
                (prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % svgOverlay.length
            );
            state.scene.add(m);
        };

        Object.values(nodes).forEach((node) => {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                console.log(node);
            }
        });

        return (
            <group dispose={null}>
                {Object.values(nodes).map((node, index) => {
                    if (node.isMesh) {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <primitive
                                    key={index}
                                    object={node}
                                    rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
                                    <mesh
                                        ref={shirt}
                                        geometry={node.geometry}
                                        material={node.material}
                                        position={[0, 0, 0]}
                                        onPointerDown={({ point, face }) => {
                                            AddDecal(point, face);
                                        }}>
                                        <Decal
                                            position={[0, 0.1005, 0]}
                                            rotation={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
                                            scale={[0.52 * 1, 0.6 * 1, 0.6 * 1]}
                                            map={texture}
                                        />
                                    </mesh>
                                </primitive>
                            </>
                        );
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                })}
            </group>
        );
    }
```